# Where to package properties file in Spring Boot war file?

Tags: spring-boot, war, directory-structure, properties-file

I have a controller file as follows:

```
@Controller
@PropertySource("file:config/code.properties")
public class ActionController {
    //...
```

I would like to package this as a war file. Where should the `config` folder be located in the project structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using springboot , you could put all your resources like the property file etc under your `resources` (src/main/resources) folder and it will be present in the jar or war created.

> SpringApplication loads properties from application.properties files
> in the following locations and adds them to the Spring Environment:
>
> A `/config` subdirectory of the current directory.
> The current directory.
> A classpath `/config` package .
> The classpath root.

You could also use the following command line parameter to specify the path yourself, if you want the file to be present externally outside the war for instance :

```
--spring.config.location=${workspace_loc:/YOURPROYECTNAME}/src/main/resources/

$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Please read [Official Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#:%7E:text=Spring%20Boot%20lets%20you%20externalize,line%20arguments%20to%20externalize%20configuration.) .

How to use a properties file , one way is to :

```
@Configuration
@Profile("code")
@PropertySource("file:/{selected location}/code.properties")
public class CodeTestClass {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public boolean test() {
        System.out.println(env.getProperty("code.test"));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if let's say my src/main/resources currently contain a `static` folder, and a `templates` folder, then my `config` folder should be on the same level as these two other folders?

Comment: Yes, if your application.properties are on the same level `src/main/resources` it will be automatically copied into the war by default.

Comment: That was where I put them, but I am still getting this error: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config/code.properties (No such file or directory)

Comment: Oh you have changed the `application.properties` name to `code.properties` , in that case you have to use the `spring.config.name` to set the properties file name to `code`, so that springboot will know the changed file name.

Comment: No, I still have application.properties. This is a separate config file

Comment: First of all if the file is under the src/main/resources it should be present in the war as well, so try to explode the war to make sure the file is included, after that if you need to load the values in your particular file in the application there are several method one of which is to use the @PropertySource  to specify the file